# Tensor Flow: Simple Network Surgery (dropping first layers)

Tags: tensorflow

Assume you have a trained network that is comprised by five layers represented as **L1->L2->L3->L4->L5**. 
Here, L1, is the *input* layer, comprised by a tf.placeholder.

How can you *fix* the output of a middle layer, like L3, to a value specified by the user and run a forward pass to see the output values of L5? In other words in this scenario we would like to treat L3 as the starting input layer and ignore L1 and L2 altogether.

Finally, assume that there is **no** need for a backward pass: i.e., we only want to evaluate and not train further the model.

Thanks!

Comment: you can feed values directly to L3 using `feed_dict`. You can also use `contrib.graph_editor` to rewire things, here's an example -- https://github.com/yaroslavvb/notebooks/blob/master/simple_rewiring.ipynb

Comment: make L1 and L2 as identity and pass the value from user to L1

Answer (score 3):

We need to make L1 and L2 as identity operations and pass the input directly to L3.

1. We need to load the model using the checkpoints.

   ```
    graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
       saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint_path + '.meta')
       session = tf.Session(graph=graph)
       saver.restore(session, checkpoint_path)
   ```
2. Lets say the name of the operations in L1 and L2 are 'l1' and 'l2'.We need to take the node and change the op to identity for L1 and L2 and for L3, change the input.

   ```
         graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
         for node in graph_def.node:
             if node.name == "L3":
             # Change its input from the output of L2 to the original input tensor op name.
                 node.input[1] = "input"
             if node.name == "L1" or node.name == "L2":
                 # For L1 and L2, change its op to Identity
                 node.op = "Identity"
   ```

   The detailed description can be found in
   https://github.com/TheMoskowitz/tensorflow-surgery/blob/master/Tensorflow_Surgery.ipynb